# What is the silent install command for Docker for windows 10?

Tags: windows, docker, command, silent-installer, mdt

I am deploying windows 10 pro to a new machine using Microsoft deployment toolkit (MDT). I need to install docker for windows in that machine using MDT. I have the docker for windows.exe file downloaded from the docker official website. I need the silent installation command for this file. I tried:

```
Docker for Windows Installer.exe install --quiet
```

This command works when running in a machine where the installer .exe file resides(NB: The command is not exited automatically after installation the if I don't press enter).

But installation using this command is not working via MDT. The task sequence is stuck at the installation of docker. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Using powershell the following command seems to work: `Start-Process -FilePath "$install_root\Docker for Windows Installer.exe" -ArgumentList "install --quiet" -RedirectStandardOutput "$log_folder\docker.log" -Wait`. You need to define your own "install_root" and "log_folder".

Answer (score 1):

You can open a powershell in elevated mode and run the following command to install Docker Desktop
`start-process docker-installer.exe "install --quiet" -Wait -NoNewWindow`